# How can I sort points of rotated-rectangle?

Tags: algorithm

[image]

It is the rotated-rectangle with a degree less than 90.
It may be clock-wise or anticlock-wise. I like to sort these points as the rectangle's orignal sequence.
Like the text-annotation, 1, 2, 3, 4......

My algorithm is:
1.find the left, right, top, bottom most points, 
2.compare the top.x and the bottom.x
3.According to the compared value, It is able to find the four corners sequence. 
4.From the four corner points, compute the line function of the edge of the rectangle, then arrange the other points.

I am not sure whether there is another more efficient or elegant algorithm to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Is the rotation known?

Comment: This looks pretty reasonable, except you cannot really distinguish between e.g. +45° and -45° rotation. So your rectangle may end up either vertically or horizontally oriented.

Comment: If you have an array of coordinates of those 4*6=24 points, rotated or not, why not just use the respective array index? Or do you receive those 24 points from something you have no control of and in an arbitrary order?

Comment: the rotation is unknown, but the angle will be between than +90 and -90. The points are getting from image processing output, so I don't know the respective array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the rectangle has been rotated clockwise by some amount less than 90 degrees.  In that case, notice that the (i+1)th point in the top row is always below and to the right of the ith point.  So we can peel off rows:

1. Sort all points in decreasing order by their y co-ordinate (i.e. from top to bottom).
2. Put these sorted points in a linked list.  (This isn't necessary, but makes point removal more efficient.)
3. Set i = 1.
4. Set lastX = -inf.
5. Set p to point to the first element in the sorted list of points.  If there are no elements remaining, we are done.
6. Starting at p, scan through the list of points until you find a point whose x co-ord is greater than lastX, indicating that it's to the right of the previous point added.  (On the first iteration of every row, this will always take the first point in the list.)
7. If such a point can be found:

   - Remove this point from the linked list and label it i.
   - Set p to the next point in the list.
   - Set i = i + 1.
   - Set lastX to the x co-ordinate of the point just added.
   - Goto 6 to find the next point in this row.

   Otherwise:

   - We have finished this row, and all points in it have been removed from the linked list.  Goto 4 to start the next row.

This is an O(n^2) algorithm, because once the rightmost point in a row has been found, it wastefully walks through all remaining points before starting at the top to process the next row.  This is probably good enough, but **the time complexity can be reduced to O(nlog n)** by maintaining a separate linked list containing all points ordered from left to right, and providing an extra field in each node in the top-to-bottom list that points to the corresponding node in the left-to-right list.  Since the rightmost point in the top row is always the rightmost point in the entire set of points, we can detect when a row has finished in just O(1) time by testing whether the point just removed corresponds to the last point in the entire left-to-right list.  Whenever a point is removed from the top-to-bottom list, it must also be removed from the left-to-right list.

**But what if the rectangle was rotated anticlockwise?**  As commenter n.m. points out, there is no way to distinguish this case from a clockwise rotation without further information: an n by m rectangle rotated anticlockwise by d degrees looks exactly like an m by n rectangle rotated clockwise by (90-d) degrees.  If you have some other information that distinguishes these cases, then anticlockwise rotations can be handled using the same algorithm as before, but noting the width of the first (or any) row, and rearranging labels afterward.